# Do I have to close HINTERNET on exit?

Tags: exit, handle, wininet

Do I have to close HINTERNET handles from (wininet.h), before exiting my application?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did your computer burst into flames?

Comment: yeah, I tried, but I thought, that a connection like to an ftp server could have to be closed, so that the ftpserver "knows" it's over (I'm not really into this stuff...)